# Select2 - need a event when drop down list is formed after opening the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I am using **select2 jquery plugin**

I am using `open` event

```
var select2 = $('select').select2();
select2.on("select2:open", () => {
   // I want to do some code here with $('.select2-results__option')
   //$('.select2-results__option').size() is not equal to actual elements 
});
```

This event triggers when we click the dropdown. but I am not getting the dropdown elements in this event.

I have 2000 dropdown elements. but in open event I am not getting that. Is there any event to detect the dropdown list is filled or not.

Comment: If you're just trying to get the elements -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187672/how-to-get-all-the-values-in-a-select2-dropdown

Comment: @rashleighp I am not using `query` also I need the elements after the `open event`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I tried to remove an item after open.

You could use a async function to check if the list is complete:

```
select2.on("open", function (e) {
   asyncCheck();
});

async asyncCheck() {
  // Waiting for 0 milliseconds was enough for me, maybe you need to increase the value
  await new Promise(resolve => window.setTimeout(resolve, 0));

  // Here comes your check, if list is completly populated ...
}
```

But be aware, that this **will not work with IE 11** as async and Promise are not supported in IE 11 (see [Promises](https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) and [async function](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions) from *Can I Use*

My workaround for IE 11 looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(checkContinuously());

function checkContinuously() {
  // Do your check here
  setTimeout(checkContinuouslyForNullOption, 100);
}
```

But is has the obvious drawback of always executing the check and **theoretically could cause a stack overflow** as it uses recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch 'results:all' event of select2 itself (not DOM).

Here from Select2.prototype._registerEvents:

```
this.on('query', function (params) {
  if (!self.isOpen()) {
    self.trigger('open', {});
  }

  this.dataAdapter.query(params, function (data) {
    self.trigger('results:all', {
      data: data,
      query: params
    });
  });
});
```

as we can see open is triggered before querying dataAdapter, that's because you don't have options in its handler I guest.

```
select2.on("results:all", function (args) { console.log(args.data);});
```

Comment: I want to do some operations on `$('.select2-results__option')` elements inside `open` event. I get the data inside `select:open` event but did not get the `$('.select2-results__option')` elements

Answer (score 0):

Sadly `select2:open` event fires BEFORE the actual options are loaded...

However, you can create a `MutationObserver`([mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)) like so:

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    if (mutations[0].addedNodes.length > 0) {
        document
            .querySelectorAll('.select2-container--open .select2-results__option')
            .forEach(optionRendered => {
                // do something with optionRendered
            });
    }
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector('body'), {
    attributes: false,
    childList: true,
    characterData: false,
    subtree: true
});
```

You are basically checking if something was added to body and if it was, try to find the thing what you are looking for and try to do something with it.

You can use this approach e.g. for styling the rendered option without actually retriggering `.select2()`.

Answer (score -1):

One way of finding if there are options or not is
`$('#select').find("option").length` which provides the number of options there are.

Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pjoriginal/zhkq5Lpo/1/)

Comment: @murli2308 added a fiddle

Comment: Doesn't answer question.