# get all data from select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a simple select2 input field:
https://select2.org

```
$('.inputField').select2({
   tags: true
});
```

The user can add values if there are not available.
Now I have a button, which calls a function getData()

```
function getDatat() {
   $('.inputField').select2('data');
}
```

This function gets the value of the selected data.
But I would like to have all data. Also the unselected data is in the dropdown menu.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Can't you just get the `<option>` elements from the underlying `<select>`? That should include all of the available options.

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187672/how-to-get-all-the-values-in-a-select2-dropdown?rq=1

Comment: How did you provide the "data" to [tag:select2] in the first place?